# How to Subclass UINavigationController With a subview Custom Bottom Tab Bar

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I have a custom bottom tab bar that works if I add it as a subView to any of my views, but I would love for it to be part of the UINavigationController so I don't need to keep track of it in every view initialization. Is there a way to do this?

I can't add it as a subView of navigationBar because I think it is out of the frame and the touches don't register on the tab bar.

I can't subclass the navigationController because apple doesn't let you. So how do I get this working?

Comment: for that put your code here to review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true that Apple won't let you subclass a UINavigationController. As of iOS 6, it is allowed, however, I don't think that would help you anyway. I think the best way to do this is with a custom container controller. If you start with a UIViewController in IB, you can put your custom tab bar at the bottom (or just leave space for it and add it in code), and add a container view that fills the rest of the space. You can delete the default controller you get with that container view, and replace it with a navigation controller. As you navigate through your content controllers, your tab bar will remain in place.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution. I'm still a bit unsure how to access the tab view controller from any of my views on the navigation controller since it won't be passed along like the navigation controller is.

Comment: @EvanLayman, what do you mean by tab view controller? Do you mean the container controller with the tab bar in its view? You can access the parent controller from any of your navigation controller's content controllers with self.navigationController.parentViewController

Comment: Ah of course thanks. I will try this soon and mark this as correct answer when I get it working.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do this in code? I've created two views, one is my tab bar, and the other is the remaining space. I tried to do `[self.navigationController.view setFrame:remainingSpaceFrame]; [self.view addSubview:self.navigationController.view];` but it didn't inject the nav controller into the space.

Comment: @EvanLayman, it you want to do this in code, you have to use the custom container controller api, which is too involves for me to answer in a comment. Is there a reason you don't want to do it in the storyboard. It's much easier there.

Comment: I am just not very familiar with IB is the reason I asked. I just created a xib for my ContainerController and added a NavigationController and my TabView but I can't change the height of the navcontroller, and I can't figure out what I wire up the ContainerController's view property to.

Comment: I got it working using the custom container controller API. Thanks for your recommendation.